# Is there an expression for getting number of times to divide an even number by 2 to get an odd number?

Tags: number-theory

I found a function $f$ to basically say, given any two integers $i\geq 0$ and $j\geq 0$, then $f(i,j)=x$ where $x>0$, will tell you that if you divide $x$ by $2$, $i$ times, then you will get an odd number $\leq x$ (like the first odd number in the sequence of dividing by 2). And every integer $x>0$ can be represented by some $i\geq0$ and $j\geq0$. I have also proved this to be true.

Does there exist something like this that someone discovered already or am I the first?

---

**Edit:**

```
f(3,4)=72
f(0,5)=11
f(17,6)=1703936
f(6,2)=320
```

Comment: It is really hard to discover something not already discovered.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order You have defined $\nu_2(n)$

Comment: @Will, I don't quite understand the p-adic function...

Comment: but does it tell you how to solve for $v$?

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote, so it balances out. Perhaps you could give some examples of your function. I guess it is not quite the 2-adic valuation, as you are taking two  numbers $i,j$ instead of one. In any case, examples would help.

Comment: ok I added 4 sample tests.

Comment: What is $j$ in relation to the function?

Comment: Am I confused, or is "the largest odd number less than $x$" equal to $x-1$ for an even number $x$?

Comment: So what is $j$ supposed to do if $f(i,j) = f(j)$? And you think that if you divide $72$ by $2$ $3$ times, then you get the largest odd number $\leq x$? Do you want to recheck that? :)

Comment: I might of mis-phrased the wording, I have edited the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears
$$  f(i,j) = 2^i \cdot (2j+1)   $$

Comment: Ok, never mind then, it seems this function is already known to the public...

Comment: @omega Don't ask a question in math thinking you found out something new because chances are you didn't. It's better to ask what concept already exists so you can learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the description be a lot simpler as "Given non-negative integers $i, j$ with $j$ odd, let $f(i, j) = 2^i * j?$ I don't quite understand why you make $j$ into $2j+1$.

Comment: No, it would not. Based off of his examples, your function does not work.

Comment: @Ryker I understand the numbers would be different. I'm just saying, OP is defining his function as $f(i, j) = 2^i (2j + 1)$, (as far as I can tell) but I'm just saying I don't see why he doesn't just make it $2^i (j)$. For example $f(3,4)$ would be $f(3,9)$ instead. That just makes more sense to me.

Comment: Not even omega knows how to define it, judging from his original post, so why would you redefine it for him?

Comment: Well if you look at his examples it's pretty clear that $f(i,j) = 2^i (2j + 1)$, as Will Jagy said. Whatever. I'm just saying it makes more sense intuitively to make $j$ mean $j$ instead of $2j + 1$.